# login redirect don't work on the server

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I developed a plugin for wordpress and I want to redirect different roles to different pages after login. I use below code and it works on my localhost (I use xamp) , but when I upload my plugin to server it doesn't work! and it just remain in `"wp-login.php"` after logining in and ofcourse the page goes white.

Code:

```
function loginRedirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){   
    global $user;
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) 
        {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return home_url()."/wp-admin/";
        } else if ( in_array( 'manager', $user->roles ) )
        {
           return  home_url()."/wp-admin/admin.php?page=creat_mysite_list_entry";             
        }
        else if ( in_array( 'jobholder', $user->roles ) )
        {
            if(have_contract_user($user->ID))
            {
                return home_url()."/wp-admin/admin.php?page=creat_mysite_register_entry";
            }
            else
            {
                return wp_logout_url();
            }
        }
    }                          
 }
add_filter("login_redirect", "loginRedirect", 10, 3);
```

Comment: Do you have WP-Debug set to true? this may provide some insight to the error if the page is blank.

Comment: @MrHunter How should I set it to true?

Comment: Open the `wp-config.php` file in the main directory and look for `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` and set it to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Comment: @MrHunter thx for your response. I set it to true and now I have this error in `wp-login.php` page above the login form:  `on line 414

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tqcenter/public_html/wordpressf/wp-config.php:1) in /home/tqcenter/public_html/wordpressf/wp-login.php on line 426
Ø¯Ø§Ø±Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø¹ØµÙˆÙ…Ù‡` and also after logining in I have a lot of error in wp-login.pho . how can I handle it?

Comment: It seems like another plugin or piece of code is outputting text and causing you to not be able to modify the headers. What is this all about `Ø¯Ø§Ø±Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø¹ØµÙˆÙ…Ù‡` ?

Comment: @MrHunter I use persian version of wordpress... the symbols are beacause of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()`

```
ob_start
```

goes top of the redirection and `ob_flush` goes end
like this

```
ob_start();
header('Location:custompage.php');
ob_flush();
```